# PostgreSQL foreign table network load when using where with nested select

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database (local) that fetches a lot of data from another PostgreSQL database (remote).

The remote table is a foreign table in the local database.

My problem is that when I SELECT with a WHERE condition, that has a nested SELECT, from the foreign table the whole table is moved over the network before the WHERE is applied.

But if I actually list the IDs in the WHERE condition, exactly the same values as in the nested SELECT, only the result of the WHERE are moved over the network.

```
SELECT * FROM bi.booking WHERE book_id IN (1,2,3, ... ,9999999)
```

Takes around 2-3sec

```
SELECT * FROM bi.booking WHERE book_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(book_id) FROM bi.temp_new_booking_history)
```

Takes over 20 minutes because of the whole bi.booking table is moved over the network first.

The goal here is to only move the data matching the a subset of id in a local table.

I have tried few things unsuccessfully so far.

string_agg to build a list, that gives an error on the IN part of the query, "operator does not exist: bigint = text"

array_agg to bild a array, that also gives an error on the IN part of the query, "operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]"

## UPDATE - 14.12.2022 14:12

After few good pointers in the comments I wanted to add the result of EXPLAIN for few versions of this query

**Original**
Query

```
SELECT * FROM bi.booking WHERE book_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(book_id) FROM bi.temp_new_booking_history)
```

EXPLAIN

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=177.00..39787.58 rows=625697 width=373)"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=76.58..80.23 rows=366 width=8)"
"        Group Key: temp_new_booking_history.book_id"
"        ->  Seq Scan on temp_new_booking_history  (cost=0.00..75.66 rows=366 width=8)"
"  ->  Foreign Scan on booking  (cost=100.43..108.47 rows=1 width=1538)"
```

**Original with hardcoded list of IDs**
Query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM keahotelsl26.booking WHERE book_id IN (1,2,3,4,...,366);
```

EXPLAIN

```
"Foreign Scan on booking  (cost=100.42..3047.70 rows=366 width=1538)"
```

**Suggestiond from Laurenz Albe**
Query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT b.* FROM bi.booking AS b WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM bi.temp_new_booking_history AS h WHERE b.book_id = h.book_id)
```

EXPLAIN

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=177.00..39783.92 rows=312848 width=373)"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=76.58..80.23 rows=366 width=8)"
"        Group Key: h.book_id"
"        ->  Seq Scan on temp_new_booking_history h  (cost=0.00..75.66 rows=366 width=8)"
"  ->  Foreign Scan on booking b  (cost=100.43..108.47 rows=1 width=1538)"
```

Comment: What do you get for `EXPLAIN SELECT b.* FROM bi.booking AS b WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM bi.temp_new_booking_history AS h WHERE b.book_id = h.book_id)` ?

Comment: Do you have "(use_remote_estimate 'true')"?  Are both tables foreign, or just booking?

Comment: What versions of Postgres on both ends?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for the reply, here is the result of the EXPLAIN

"QUERY PLAN"
"Hash Semi Join  (cost=639.83..166813.69 rows=312848 width=373)"
"  Hash Cond: (b.book_id = h.book_id)"
"  ->  Foreign Scan on booking b  (cost=100.00..160759.91 rows=625697 width=1538)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=509.37..509.37 rows=2437 width=8)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on temp_new_booking_history h  (cost=0.00..509.37 rows=2437 width=8)"

Sorry for the format, not sure how to post code snippets in comments

Comment: @jjanes thanks for your reply, yes I have that option on the Foreign server, isn't that correct?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for the reply, local is v11.14 remote is v11.16

Comment: @oskarom you don't post code in the comment you update your question with it properly formatted.

Comment: Hm. I don't think you will be able to get a better plan here. You might be able to force a nested loop join with the foreign table on the inner side, but I doubt that that would be a win.

Comment: Thanks again for the replies, I just updated the question with EXPLAIN, I think it is really interesting how the cost changes if the list of IDs is hardcoded. This is actually the desirable result, makes me wonder if there would be a way to get the result from the sub query as an string...

Comment: For these plans, what are the actual timings?

Comment: For what is worth, none of the plans you show is sending all of "booking" over the network.  The slowness would apparently be due to the latency of requesting one row at a time, not the bandwidth of sending the whole table.  It would probably be better to package up the subselect into an array and send one request to the foreign server for the whole thing, but I don't see a way to do that.  That might be a feature request targeted at the postgres_fdw module.